# Using multi version library with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I need to have different versions of pandas to be able to import either 0.13 or 0.14 version.
I gone in the path "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages" and changing the directory name of pandas to pandas_013 but I get the following error.

Has someone a solution to have multi version library with python 2.7?

```
>>> import pandas_013
No module named pandas.compat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas_013\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 37, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:55034)
ImportError: No module named pandas.compat
```

Comment: do you need to use both versions side-by-side in the same code base?

Comment: not really an obligation. I want to choose by importing the good package.

Comment: Why not use git to switch back and forth? Or virtualenv. Monkey patching package names in site packages can only lead to a universe of pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use multiple versions, they should be inside your package, probably in a `lib` package. So then you have `mypackage.lib.pandas_013` and `mypackage.lib.pandas_014`. Next, you need to fix those libraries - remember that they will be filled with imports like the one which errored for you (`pandas.compat`). So that needs to be changed to `mypackage.lib.pandas_013.compat` and `mypackage.lib.pandas_014.compat`, as does every other reference to the original `pandas` package. An IDE with refactoring or some sed-fu can help here.

Comment: I don't understand the mypackage.lib.pandas_013. Do you want to say that I must have two directory 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas_013' and 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas_014'? Which refactoring do you advice me? Thanks

Comment: Oh - did you mean to use pandas from a Python shell, not in your own code? Sorry, you can just use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/) then. I thought you wanted both accessible simultaneously (i.e. from the same interpreter).

Comment: Thx Ryan. I need to be able to do either import pandas_013 or import pandas_014 but the needs is not to do the two in a same script. I will look for virtualenv.